# magento 2 contact us add multiple recipients

Tags: forms, magento, magento2, contacts

task:

- create form "contact us"
- send data from the form to 2 mails

im create form but magento 2 does not provide such resourses multiplie sending

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU0I3.jpg

I was looking for a solution to the problem and found a way:
completely rewrite the contact form saveing controller
and give it your transport method in which you need to assign the number of additional emails

if someone came across such or similar implementation, please help with an example

Comment: You have to customise in contact us

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that on Magento 2. You should create your own module, or you can download this one... for free!

https://marketplace.magento.com/visions-contact.html